# Pass default form field value to Database MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, methods

I have created a site for users to edit their userdata, the form fields are prefilled with their current data and they can edit what they want.

My problem is that when using post method in my form, it only passes the altered fields, not the field with default values, how can i get it to pass also the default values to my controller?

EDIT code from form

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Fornavn</th>

    <td>
      <input name="Fornavn" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" FirstName "]" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Efternavn</th>

    <td>
      <input name="Efternavn" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" LastName "]" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>

    <td>
      <input name="Email" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" Email "]" required>
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <th>Telefon</th>

    <td>
      <input name="Telefonnummer" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" PhoneNumber "]" required>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Avatar</th>

    <td>
      <input id="file" type="file" name="file">
      <br />
      <p style="font-size:11px">
        For bedste resultat, venligst brug et billede i størrelse 200x200 PX. (Ellers resizer vi det for dig, og det ser herrens ud.)
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
  <h4>Adresse</h4>
  <br>


  <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>Vejnavn</th>

      <td>
        <input name="Road" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" Road "]" required>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th>Vejnummer</th>

      <td>
        <input name="RoadNumber" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" RoadNumber "]" required>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th>By</th>

      <td>
        <input name="Town" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" Town "]" required>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th>Postnummer</th>

      <td>
        <input name="ZipCode" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" ZipCode "]" required>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th>Land</th>

      <td>
        <input name="Country" class="center-content" type="text" value="@row[" Country "]" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="@Url.Action(" UserProfile ", "Home ")" class="button button-big">
      <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/Content/img/ui-icon/corporate-w.png ")" style="height: 35px; margin-top: -6px;" />Tilbage til min profil!</a>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" value="Upload" class="button button-big">
      <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/Content/img/ui-icon/corporate-w.png ")" style="height: 35px; margin-top: -6px;" />Gem Mine Ændringer!</button>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult EditPrivateUser(EventCrushV001.Models.PrivateUser user, HttpPostedFileBase file, string path, string sqlPath)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            try
            {
                var PID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Avatar"), PID);
                sqlPath = Path.Combine(("../Upload/Avatar"), PID);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Error handling here
        }

        var con = GetDefaultConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Private_User Set (PW=@PW, Birthdate=@Birthdate, FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, Email=@Email, PhoneNumber=@PhoneNumber, Avatar=@Avatar) Where (UserID=@UserID)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PW", user.Password);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", user.Fødselsdag);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", user.Fornavn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", user.Efternavn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", user.Telefonnummer);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressID", adrId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Avatar", sqlPath);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["id"]);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Model:

```
public class PrivateUser
{
    public string Fødselsdag {get; set;}
    public string Fornavn { get; set; }
    public string Efternavn { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Telefonnummer { get; set; }
    public string Brugernavn { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Vejnavn { get; set; }
    public int Postnummer { get; set; }
    public string By { get; set; }
    public string Land { get; set; }
    public int Vejnummer { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }
}
```

A very thin model ;)

Comment: It should post back the values if you bound them to form fields correctly. Can you show us your code?

Comment: You need to provide some code as well

Comment: What do you mean it does not pass the fields with default values. If you have form controls for your properties they will be posted. Show you model and view

Comment: Sorry for not pasting code.. :)

Comment: You also need to show us the model that it is bound too.

Comment: Have you heard of html helpers - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fornavn)`?

Comment: No i havent, im new to C# and MVC, but will give it a look :)